# When should one use `make-instance` over calling the EIEIO class constructor function?

Tags: eieio

When an EIEIO class is defined:

```
(defclass my-test ()
  ((slot1 :initform 0)))
```

A constructor function of the same name is also defined. However, there's also `make-instance`, which also makes a new instance of the class.

```
(let ((a (make-instance 'my-test)) ; -> #s(my-test 0)
      (b (my-test))) ; -> #s(my-test 0)
  (equal a b))
;; -> t
```

I see that they are different in at least one way: the contructor function prevents one from making an instance of an abstract class, whereas `make-instance` will ignore it and create an instance anyways.

```
(defclass my-abstract ()
  ((slot1 :initform 0))
  :abstract t)

(make-instance 'my-abstract) ; -> #s(my-abstract 0)
(my-abstract) ; (error "Class my-abstract is abstract")
```

Given that, when should one use `make-instance`, and when should one use the constructor function (`(my-test)`)?

Comment: I imagine that in almost all cases, you want to use the c'tor. The doc (`C-h i g(eieio)making new objects`) says: `To create an object from a class symbol, use ‘make-instance’.`, but that's about the only exception mentioned.